# "certcli 1.0 type library" vs CertComLIB vs "Certenroll 1.0 type library" vs "CertEnc"

Tags: encryption, certificate, x509certificate, com-interop, certenroll

I'm trying to work with client side certificate enrollment via COM Interop

[image]

Which library is appropriate for use?

Answer (score 0):

For operating systems starting with Windows Vista/Windows Server 2008, you need to use CertEnroll library. Also, CertCli library may be necessary if you want to utilize `ICertRequest` interface (out-of-band certificate enrollment).